# SSD disk active time always 100%

Tags: windows, ssd, performance, freeze, windows-defender

I need your help because Im going crazy with my laptop. The problem is that my SSD disk's (NVMe ADATA SX6000PNP) active time is basically constantly 100% and - I assume because of that - my laptop is quite often unusable (sometimes it freezes for minutes, or just doesn't respond to my inputs/commands) - CPU and memory usage is normal, so it must be caused by the disk (at least that's my assumption). It also uses 100% after a full restart, without launching any program (eg. Chrome)
Sometimes it takes literally an hour to do a restart (after verifying me (with camera (biometric: face) or password) the login screen just shows the loading icon constantly)

Task manager/Performance photo (I wasn't able to insert directly a photo in my post due to lack of reputation, that's why the link):
https://i.ibb.co/bPJtBL3/tm.png

I tried to see in resource monitor what uses that much disk, usually MsMpEng.exe (win defender?), win update and some system tasks was in the first places (by write).

My config:

ASUS-ZenBook UX434FLC

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz 2.30 GHz

16.0 GB RAM

NVMe ADATA SX6000PNP SSD 500 GB

Windows 10 Home Version: 20H2 Build: 19042.1237

I tried to google these "symtomps" and tried several solutions, but nothing has helped so far.

Any advice/idea/experience? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to see in resource monitor what uses that much disk, usually
> MsMpEng.exe (win defender?)

Yes - it is Defender.

You have a bad virus.

Back up the machine and re-install Windows.

Comment: I have just installed Bitdefender antivirus, so Microsoft Defender has been turned off automatically (and neither MsMpEng.exe is running anymore). Still, I observe the same issues, 100% disk active time...

Comment: Defender stays active in the background. Bit Defender is likely picking up the same virus.

Comment: I know, but if it's turned off due to another antivirus software, it doesn't stay active in the background (I checked, there is no process and also the service itself (Microsoft Defender) is stopped now)

Comment: I have SSD drives on 3 of my Windows 10 / 11 machines, and nothing drives my SSD to that kind of level. I can run things when updates are downloading and doing initial install. I can run a Repair Install to the last step and run things. Nothing I do in the normal course of things uses my SSDs to 100 percent.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect its PCI express Link State Power Management issue. Because first you have a NVME ssd, second read/write amount is very low (below 1mb in your screenshot), third average response time is high, forth its a laptop and windows on defaults sets PCI express to maximum power saving. Go to advanced power settings and try changing PCI express Link State Power Management to off.

Here is more information on this thread: [SSD disk active time 100 percent frequently on idle](https://superuser.com/questions/1818465/ssd-disk-active-time-100-percent-frequently-on-idle/1818466#1818466)