# SSD disk active time 100 percent frequently on idle

Tags: ssd, performance, windows-11, freeze, nvme

I am using windows 11 and I have 2TB M.2 NVME SSD on my laptop. My disk active time is regularly hitting 100 percent on idle. Even tho there is almost no read and write activity at all. Even when my wifi is off. My system sometimes freeze for few seconds. I also get high average response time. Generally right after the freeze. Resource manager shows the only process is using the disk is system. And the files are NTFS volume log, NTFS master file table and NVIDIA debug log. Which shouldn't cause such impact. What is the problem and how can I fix 100 percent disk active time on my ssd?

[image: Task manager and resource monitor on ssd disk usage screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue. The problem was PCI Express Link State Power Management was set to maximum power saving. Setting it to off fixed the 100 percent disk problem. Also my system doesn't freeze anymore. To set it off go to `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings\Change advanced power settings\PCI express\Link state power management` set it to `off` for both on battery and plugged in. Here is the screenshot of advanced power settings and task manager after I changed the settings.

> There are basically 2 levels of power management in the PCI Express
> options. The difference between these 2 options are the power savings
> versus the Latency (Time to recover from the Sleep state). If you
> select the first option Moderate Power Savings, the power savings are
> less, but the time to recover from the Sleep state (latency) is much
> shorter. If you select the Maximum Power Savings, the power savings
> are greater, but the time to recover from the Sleep state (latency) is
> much longer.

> PCI Express has "active-state" power management, which lowers power
> consumption when the bus is not active (that is, no data is being sent
> between components or peripherals). On a parallel interface such as
> PCI, no transitions occur on the interface until data needs to be
> sent.
> In contrast, high-speed serial interfaces such as PCI Express require
> that the interface be active at all times so that the transmitter and
> receiver can maintain synchronization. This is accomplished by
> continuously sending idle characters when there is no data to send.
> The receiver decodes and discards the idle characters. This process
> consumes additional power, which impacts battery life on portable and
> handheld computers.
> To address this issue, the PCI Express specification creates two
> low-power link states and the active-state power management (ASPM)
> protocol. When the PCI Express link goes idle, the link can transition
> to one of the two low-power states. These states save power when the
> link is idle, but require a recovery time to resynchronize the
> transmitter and receiver when data needs to be transmitted. The longer
> the recovery time (or latency), the lower the power usage. The most
> frequent implementation will be the low-power state with the shortest
> recovery time.

[Quoted from "Ronnie Vernon" on MS answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/what-is-link-state-power-management-under-pci/86da5bfa-fa36-4547-ba84-3714eb27df31?page=1)

[image: Advanced power options menu]
[image: Disk usage after changing the setting]

Comment: I'd be curious what results you get with power management set to "moderate" as described in your quotes. Presumably under maximum savings your device is spending a lot of time reading a packet of data from the disk, going to sleep and then being woken up a fraction of a second later to read another packet of data and that 100% idle is spent mostly waiting for the PCIE link to retrain before sending data. Nice find though and a good explanation of what the setting does.

Comment: @Mokubai Thank you. I accidentally discovered it. I saw an old post suggesting modifying hard disk turn off time on power options. Then I saw PCI express power management option and gave it a shot and it worked. Moderate power savings also works without the problem. I set my "on battery" to moderate and "plugged in" to off.

Comment: As an additional piece of information. If you hover over the "On battery" after changing the setting to "moderate" a tooltip shows "Attempt to use the L0S state when link is idle" while "Maximum" shows "Attempt to use the L1 state when link is idle". L0S seems to just turn off a transmitter but keeps the link ostensibly "ready" while L1 turns the link and it's clock off completely which is why performance becomes awful. L1 means the entire link must be brought up, the clock synchronised and then the data links trained.

Comment: Wikipedia [Active State Power Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_State_Power_Management) says "Currently, two low power modes are specified by the PCI Express 2.0 specification; L0s and L1 mode. L0s concerns setting low power mode for one direction of the serial link only, usually downstream of the PHY controller. **L1 shuts off PCI Express link completely, including the reference clock signal, until a dedicated signal (CLKREQ#) is asserted**, and results in greater power reductions though with the penalty of greater exit latency."